# java string substring retrieval

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I have a string out of which I wish to extract out a substring. 
`String temp = abc-def-p1-p2-p3-p4-p5.uvx.xyz`

I wish to retrieve the string in place of p1, p2, p3, p4. p1, p2, p3, p4 can have different values, however the format of the temp string will be constant to one mentioned above.

Currently I am planning to extract out values using below function:

```
public void extractSubString(String temp) {

  String[] parts = temp.split("-");

  String p1 = parts[2];
  String p2 = parts[3];
  String p3 = parts[4];
  String p4 = parts[5];
}
```

However this does not seem to the cleanest approach to retrieve the substring.
Is there a better way to obtain the values?

Thanks

Comment: What's not clean about it?

Comment: For starters, you can do bounds checking...

Comment: *"Is there a better way?"* You can also use a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), which will allow better control against variances in the data. Whether regex is *better* depends on your situation.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're positive that p1,p2,p3,p4 can't contain a "-" in themselves (I mean as their value), I think your solution is fine. You could do it with a regular expression, but that would be overkill for this case imo. Of course *if* p1-p4 might contain a "-" then you'll end up parsing incorrect values